# fatal error: 'mysql/mysql.h' not found (but added in path)

Tags: mysql, path, compile, make, c++

I use MAC OS X El capitan 10.11.5
I am trying to understand and execute some code on c++ (it is a lot of files and i am new to c++ a), but when i type "make" to compile everything, it returns the following message

```
main_func/main_offline_ecap_ratelumi.cpp:16:10: fatal error:     'mysql/mysql.h' file not found
```

This is what i did: 
when i type "type -a mysql" it says
mysql in /opt/local/bin/mysql 
but the file mysql.h is in /opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql 
so i added the path of the mysql.h file in the .profile file and in the .bashrc file (first in only one of them and then on both at the same time) like this
for .bashrc file

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql
```

and in the .profile file

```
export PATH="/opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql/$PATH"
```

execute them, restore window but nothing works, the error keeps appearing after "make"

I also added the path provided by the "type command" instead of the actual path of the mysql.h file, but nothing

If i create the bash_profile (because it dos not exist in my computer) script with such file itdoes not work and erases all other paths added befor (for example i can not run ROOT-CERN anymore, so i erase the new bash_profile script and everything goes back to normal)

Also this is my PATH variable

```
/opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql//opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql/:/opt/X11/bin
```

Hope you can help
thanks a lot in advanced
cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add `-I(replace this with the path where the mysql includes are)` to your CFLAGS. The C++ compiler does not look for includes on the PATH.

Comment: i added CFLAGS = -I/opt/local/include/mysql56/mysql and then added the variable main_offline_ecap_ratelumi.o : main_func/main_offline_ecap_ratelumi.cpp $(CC)  $(CFLAG) -c main_func/main_offline_ecap_ratelumi.cpp $(ROOTINC) in the makefile. CC = g++ ,but still does not find mysql.h

Comment: You called the C++ compiler with $(CFLAG), but you should use $(CFLAGS).

Comment: o yes that was a typo in the comment , it still does not work

Comment: -I/opt/local/include/mysql56